# Acumatica: Sign Out User After Process Completion

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to sign out a user once a process is completed, I tried using the PXAccess or the PXAccessInfo classes in order to do so but did not manage to find a correct way in logging out a user. Are there any other means in signing out a user which I might have glossed over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted the standard SignOut code so it can be run from a graph extension instead of a Aspx.cs web page. It is equivalent to this SignOut menu item:

[image]

In this example I put the code in SOOrderEntry Initialize override so it signs out the current user as soon as you navigate to the SalesOrderEntry graph. You can put it in an Action event handler but I haven't tested it in a PXLongOperation context which runs in a separate thread context:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;

        if (page != null)
        {
            PX.Data.PXLogin.LogoutUser(PX.Data.PXAccess.GetUserName(), page.Session.SessionID);
            PX.Common.PXContext.Session.SetString("UserLogin", string.Empty);

            string absoluteLoginUrl = PX.Export.Authentication.AuthenticationManagerModule.Instance.SignOut();

            page.Session.Abandon();
            PX.Data.Auth.ExternalAuthHelper.SignOut(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, absoluteLoginUrl);

            PX.Export.Authentication.FormsAuthenticationModule.
            RedirectToLoginPage(PX.Data.Auth.ExternalAuthHelper.SILENT_LOGIN + "=None", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference and other users who would want to log out a user in a PXLongOperation  all they would need to do is call this function in a CustomInfo Wrapper. Example Given below:

public class LogOutInfo : IPXCustomInfo
{
     public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph) 
     {
         // Call Sign Out Logic   
     }
}